# Jenkins pipeline fails on Maven command that works in terminal

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins pipeline that builds with maven + docker and it started to raise exception since a restart of the node (amazon EC2).
At first the pipeline broke at the git checkout, failing at cloning the repository. Thus I specified the git path in the Configuration tool of my node, in Jenkins.
It fixed that issue, but now it fails running this command

```
./mvnw help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
```

When I run it in the EC2's terminal it works and prints out "0.0.1" in my case.
The exception raised in Jenkins is:

```
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] withCredentials
Masking supported pattern matches of $NEXUS_DOCKER_CREDS or $NEXUS_DOCKER_CREDS_USR or $NEXUS_DOCKER_CREDS_PSW
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ git show -s --format=format:%s _by %an_ HEAD
[Pipeline] sh
+ ./mvnw help:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version -q -DforceStdout
Exception in thread "main"
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /var/lib/jenkins/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.8.1-bin/2l5mhf2pq2clrde7f7qp1rdt5m/apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.zip.part (No such file or directory)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
at ava.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:162)
at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.downloadInternal(DefaultDownloader.java:85)
at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.download(DefaultDownloader.java:76)
at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.createDist(Installer.java:72)
at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:61)
16:03:49.888580 durable_task_monitor.go:63: exit status 1
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withCredentials
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
```

Checking the nodes, maven isn't installed but the previous commands with `./mvnw` still works.
I tried to add Maven to Jenkins' global tools and to my node's tool, after I installed it anyway and setting the path (found with `mvn -v` in the EC2 terminal).

At this point I'm really out of ideas, so any tip will be appreciated.
Thank you so much!

Comment: First if you use `./` this means search in the local directory not via the `PATH` second using wrapper within a Jenkins pipelines is usually not the best... furthermore if you configured tools configuration you should use the pipeline code to use it...something like `withMaven(...) { ...}`

Comment: Ok, I'll try to use `mvn` and not `./mvnw` after I'll have my pipeline working again, thank you. I already tried adding `tools { maven 'maven' }` but without success, is it different with `withMaven()` ?

Comment: The immediate cause of the exception is clear enough (`/var/lib/jenkins/.m2/wrapper/dists/apache-maven-3.8.1-bin/2l5mhf2pq2clrde7f7qp1rdt5m/apache-maven-3.8.1-bin.zip.part` is missing); why that's the case, I have no idea (seems like a Jenkins and/or Maven setup issue).

Comment: @torek sure I can see the error log, but the reason is what I'm trying to understand in order to fix this. With the `withMaven()` nothing seems to work

Comment: That's why I have to leave this to a Jenkins and/or Maven person. I've dealt somewhat superficially with Jenkins before (and hate it, it's evil ... or at least extremely non-Unix-friendly, it does wrong things with signals and when it does distributed compilation it makes bad assumptions about uniformity and other things like that) but don't know what bad interaction is happening here in particular.